# Multiple dropdown redirect to URL ( HTML )

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I found a custom select dropdown with button redirect code. It works with one dropdown, but I want to make two dropdown menus.
I tried adding var's for select-id2, but script stopped working and nothing happened.

```
<select id="select-id1">
    <option value="" selected="">First category</option>
    <option value="http://example.com">Example</option>
</select>

<select id="select-id2">
    <option value="" selected="">Second category</option>
    <option value="/page">Page</option>
</select>

<button onclick="siteRedirect()">GO</button>

<script>
    function siteRedirect() {
        var selectbox = document.getElementById("select-id");
        var selectedValue = selectbox.options[selectbox.selectedIndex].value;
        window.location.href = selectedValue;
    }
</script>
```

First one (select-id1) should have domain example.com, and the second one (select-id2) should add /page on the first one. So the redirection link should be example.com/page.

Is there any way to do with this code?

Comment: `document.getElementById("select-id");`, but your ids are `select-id1` and `select-id2`

Comment: I'm bad with scripts. #select-id2 is code added by my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are searching for the element with `id="select-id"`. When only `select-id1` and `select-id2` exists.

Try this:

```js
function siteRedirect() {
var select1 = document.querySelector("#select-id1"),
    select2 = document.querySelector("#select-id2");
var category = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].value,
    subcategory = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].value;
    redirect = category+subcategory;
console.log("Redirect to: "+redirect);
}
```

```html
<select id="select-id1">
<option value="" selected="">First category</option>
<option value="http://example.com">Example</option>
</select>
<select id="select-id2">
<option value="" selected="">Second category</option>
<option value="/page">Page</option>
</select>
<button onclick="siteRedirect()">GO</button>
```

Comment: Thats it! But I had to replace console.log("Redirect to: "+redirect); with window.location.href = redirect; .    Thank you!

Comment: @MarinBajic Yes, no doubt. I just logged in console the url so you could see it. Glad to help! And welcome to Stackoverflow. Keep good questions up! You can read: [What to do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so your question is marked as solved and ready to help someone with a similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting a reference to the second `<select>` element. You just added it to your HTML, your script is unaware of it.

`var selectbox2 = document.getElementById("select-id2");`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

This will make it redirect to whatever is the value of **select-id2** option element

```
<select id="select-id2">
  <option value="" selected="">Second category</option>
  <option value="/page">Page</option>
</select>
<button onclick="siteRedirect()">GO</button>
<script>
  function siteRedirect() {
    var selectbox = document.getElementById('select-id2');
    var selectedValue = selectbox.options[selectbox.selectedIndex].value;
    window.location.href = selectedValue;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this. It still opens example.com, not example.com/page

Comment: That's because you are just getting a reference to it, I edited it above.

Comment: Now it opens only /page...Wihout example.com

Comment: so change the value to http://www.example.come/whatever, or keep that value in a string and adjust it dynamically

Comment: You don't understand me. 
select-id1 = first part of the other url ( example : my site is marin.com and I want redirection to amazon.com ).
select-id2 = secound part of that url ( example : /shop ).
So when I click go, it should go to amazon.com/shop

Comment: This only offers half the solution. The answer by k3llydev is much more complete.

Answer (score 0):

You want to join split URLs together, for that, you have to concatenate the two parts and you can do it simply parsing the values on JS (as JavaScript already stores data into variables as strings, so you shouldn't have a problem with that)

The logic is pretty much like this :

```
var link1 = document.getElementById("select-id1").value;
var link2 = document.getElementById("select-id2").value;
var joined = link1 + link2

function siteRedirect() {
  window.location.href = joined;
}
```

See if that helps you

Answer (score 0):

Thats it! Thank you all, but especially to [k3llydev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5568741/k3llydev)!

So. The final code is :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select id="select-id1">
<option value="" selected="">First category</option>
<option value="example.com">Example</option>
</select>
<select id="select-id2">
<option value="" selected="">Second category</option>
<option value="/page">Page</option>
</select>
<button onclick="siteRedirect()">GO</button>

<script>
function siteRedirect() {
var select1 = document.querySelector("#select-id1"),
select2 = document.querySelector("#select-id2");
var category = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].value,
subcategory = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].value;
redirect = category+subcategory;
/*console.log("Redirect to: "+redirect);*/
window.location.href = redirect;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Solved!